# Перемножить значения input'ов и вывести результат

Tags: javascript, jquery

Как выполнить умножение двух чисел, введенных в inputы на jquery или js и результат заносить в div?

```
<input type="number" name="num1" id="num1" value="" min="10" max="1000" step="10" required>
<input type="number" name="num2" id="num2" value="" min="10" max="1000" step="10" required>
<div id="res"></div>
```

Comment: начните с этого - https://www.w3schools.com/js/default.asp

Comment: Я-то думал, что [это](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ssRUr.gif) шутка.

Comment: Что конкретно Вас интересует? Как получить значение из input? Как перемножить 2 числа? Как поместить число в div? Покажите ваш код.

Comment: попробуйте на https://jsfiddle.net написать код самостоятельно. Если не получится задайте еще раз вопрос, но уже с вашими примерами кода)

Comment: есть два инпута для ввода чисел. Нужно их перемножить и результат вывести в div

Comment: Кому нужно? Вам или Вашему преподавателю?

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/n0wp1k7c/

Comment: что за глупые вопросы (Кому нужно? Вам или Вашему преподавателю?).. я новичек в этом..

Comment: @3Darin что именно не получается и непонятно? Как получить значение из input? как строки из инпута привести к числу? Как перемножить 2 числа? Как поместить число в div?

Comment: нужно на jequery или js умножить два введенных числа и результат вывести в div. Т.е чтоб при вводе чисел сразу происходило их умножение и рядом выводился результат

Comment: @3Darin что именно не получается и непонятно? Как получить значение из input? как строки из инпута привести к числу? Как перемножить 2 числа? Как поместить число в div? **с чем именно** затруднения?

Comment: )))) мда. что я непонятно объясняю

Comment: @3Darin пока ты объясняешь задание, которое нужно сделать, а не то, что у тебя не получается с чем конкретно ты столкнулся непонятным

Answer (score 0, accepted):

можно по разному,  один из вариантов

```js
var input = document.querySelectorAll('input');
var div = document.querySelector('div');
var res;
for (let i = 0; i < input.length; i++) {
  input[i].addEventListener('input', function() {
    if (inputOne.value !== '' && inputTwo.value !== '') {
      res = inputOne.value * inputTwo.value;
      div.textContent = res;
    }
  })
}
```

```html
<input id="inputOne" type="text">
<input id="inputTwo" type="text">
<div></div>
```

Comment: благодарю! буду пробовать

Comment: В Вашем ответе недостаточно jquery

Comment: @vp_arth,  в моем ответе вообще нет JQ, но в вопросе "или JS или JQ"...

Comment: @Air, заходите [в чат](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/22462/stack-overflow--)

Answer (score 3):

Думаю стоит написать небольшой плагин для jQuery:

```js
$.fn.multiplicator = function(...selectors) {
  // получаем список полей ввода по селекторам
  let inputs = selectors.map(s => $(s));

  // функция перемножения всех значений полей ввода
  const recalc = () => inputs.reduce((r, $el) => r*parseFloat($el.val()), 1);

  // Навешиваем событие на все поля ввода, по которому производим пересчёт и обновление значения результата
  inputs.forEach($el => $el.on(this.data('event')||'blur', () => this.text(recalc())));
}

   
// Применяем наш плагин

$('#res').multiplicator('#arg1', '#arg2');
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<input id=arg1 value=1 />
<input id=arg2 value=1 />
<div id=res data-event=input></div>
```

Comment: Кажется вы спонсируете bad practice таким ответом..

Comment: Вам кажется, или ви таки уверены?

Comment: @VladimirGamalyan, есть вопросы на который при такой скудной формулировке, не то что ответить на нельзя, а просто не возможно. Согласен, вопрос не оформлен правильно, но он понятен и что бы на него ответить достаточно пары строк кода,  а бывают вопросы,  "пойди туда, не знаю куда, принеси то не знаю чего"... И что плохого в ответе?

Comment: @Air уровень знаний в данном ответе намного превышает уровень знаний в вопросе. Какой к черту this, reduce, spead оператор и т.д. если человек еще только учиться формулировать вопросы)

Comment: @TimaTru,  мой уровень знаний намного ниже вашего, лично я, из ответа  который написал  vp_arth, тоже мало что понял, мне надо вглядываться читать, спрашивать... Не вижу ничего плохого в том, что бы ответы были разнообразны, для этого надо, что бы ответ был не один, каждый подчеркнет для себя то что ему надо... А что мой ответ хорош... ?? Я пишу ответы в двух случаях, или когда точно знаю ответ или знаю плохо, но не плохо было бы проверить свои знания получив адекватную и конструктивную критику... В моем ответе уже пошаманил Qwertiy, кое что подправил, щас буду читать смотреть что к чему