# как произвести автоматическое вычитание двух полей на Js/jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

нету кода, к сожалению, не могу понять, следующее: вот допустим есть два поля: бюджет и аванс, необходимо, чтобы они в поле остаток автоматически вычетались с помощью js илиjQuery

```
$(".sub").focusout(function() {
  $("#answer").html('');
  var num1 = $("#num1").val();
  var num2 = $("#num2").val();
  var answer = num1 - num2;
  $("#answer").html(answer);
});
```

Comment: Без кода нет ответа, потрудитесь сначала сами.

Comment: Приведите код для случая когда они вычитаются неавтоматически (впишите в вопрос, нажав "править" под вопросом), потом попробуем помочь с тем, чтобы сделать автоматически.

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Перемножить значения input'ов и вывести результат](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/743565/%d0%9f%d0%b5%d1%80%d0%b5%d0%bc%d0%bd%d0%be%d0%b6%d0%b8%d1%82%d1%8c-%d0%b7%d0%bd%d0%b0%d1%87%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%b8%d1%8f-input%d0%be%d0%b2-%d0%b8-%d0%b2%d1%8b%d0%b2%d0%b5%d1%81%d1%82%d0%b8-%d1%80%d0%b5%d0%b7%d1%83%d0%bb%d1%8c%d1%82%d0%b0%d1%82)

Comment: @Air почему заминусовали ваш ответ?) Потому что в нем нет Jquery ? :D

Comment: потому что, автор, даже не постарался сам, что-то сделать)))  ответил без примера...))) это долгая история)))

Comment: @Air а понял, тут же не любят когда отвечают на подобные вопросы))

Comment: Я в том числе)), просто пример был не сложный, да и  настроение было хорошее, решил сделать добро)))  вот и получил))

Comment: @Air "Я в том числе, но по настроению" получается)

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса:  [Онлайн вычисление](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/745171/%D0%9E%D0%BD%D0%BB%D0%B0%D0%B9%D0%BD-%D0%B2%D1%8B%D1%87%D0%B8%D1%81%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5/745173#745173)

Comment: Все мы люди, все мы "человеки", есть правило, которого надо придерживаться, но иногда бывает, что можно и по хулиганить, когда соответствующее настроение...

Comment: а еще для оффтоп-общения есть чат, а не комментарии.

Answer (score 0):

Ну "автоматически" это довольно широкое понятие. Можно вычислять значение например при вводе данных в поля.

И так, HTML:

```
<input type="number" id="budget" placeholder="Бюджет">
<input type="number" id="prepayment" placeholder="Аванс">
<input type="number" id="balance" placeholder="Остаток" readonly>
```

Ничего сложного три поля типа: число, остаток я так понимаю изменять нельзя, по этому он только для чтения.

JS:

```
// Объявляем переменные
var budget = document.getElementById("budget");
var prepayment = document.getElementById("prepayment");
var balance = document.getElementById("balance");

function setBalance() {
    // Проверяем что поля бюджет и аванс заполнены
    if (budget.value && prepayment.value) {
        balance.value = parseFloat(budget.value) - parseFloat(prepayment.value)
    }
}

// Вызываем функцию setBalance при вводе в поля.
budget.addEventListener("input", setBalance)
prepayment.addEventListener("input", setBalance)
```

Результат:

*Для просмотра нажать "выполнить код"*

```js
var budget = document.getElementById("budget");
var prepayment = document.getElementById("prepayment");
var balance = document.getElementById("balance");

function setBalance() {
    if (budget.value && prepayment.value) {
        balance.value = parseFloat(budget.value) - parseFloat(prepayment.value)
    }
}

budget.addEventListener("input", setBalance)
prepayment.addEventListener("input", setBalance)
```

```html
<input type="number" id="budget" placeholder="Бюджет">
<input type="number" id="prepayment" placeholder="Аванс">
<input type="number" id="balance" placeholder="Остаток" readonly>
```

Comment: если человек уже пытается сделать что-то на jquery думаете актуально ему писать что-то на чистом js ? Он вероятно знает что это такое и уже подключил его  на странице.

Comment: @teran, А причем тут это? Если задачу можно решить на чистом js так же быстро и чисто как на jq, почему бы не использовать vanillajs?
**UPD** Ответ был дан, прежде чем код был представлен.

Comment: Спасибо огромное!