# JavaScript калькулятор. Автомтический подсчет

Tags: javascript, html

Есть калькулятор, который считает сумму при нажатии на кнопку. Как сделать чтобы он автоматически считал?

> То есть ты пишешь 10 и 10, он считает автоматически и выводит 20.
>   меняешь первое число на 11 и он автоматически вывод 21

Есть идея попробовать как то через цикл, но я не знаю как это реализовать.

```js
function sum() {
  var a1 = document.getElementById('first').value;
  var a2 = document.getElementById('second').value;
  a1 = Number.parseInt(a1);
  a2 = Number.parseInt(a2);
  a2 += a1;
  var rez = document.getElementById("rez").innerText = a2;
}

document.getElementById("go").onclick = function() {

  sum();
}
```

```html
<h1 align="center">Введите 1 и 2 число</h1>
<div class="mainn">
  <input type="text" id="first" size="10">
  <p>+</p>
  <input type="text" id="second" size="10"><br>
  <button id="go">=</button>
  <h1 id="rez"></h1>
</div>
```

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Перемножить значения input'ов и вывести результат](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/743565/%d0%9f%d0%b5%d1%80%d0%b5%d0%bc%d0%bd%d0%be%d0%b6%d0%b8%d1%82%d1%8c-%d0%b7%d0%bd%d0%b0%d1%87%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%b8%d1%8f-input%d0%be%d0%b2-%d0%b8-%d0%b2%d1%8b%d0%b2%d0%b5%d1%81%d1%82%d0%b8-%d1%80%d0%b5%d0%b7%d1%83%d0%bb%d1%8c%d1%82%d0%b0%d1%82)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Вот этот кусочек поменяйте. У вас уже всё для этого есть. Надо только правильный event повесить на input.

```
        <input type="text" id="first" size="10" onkeyup="sum()">
        <p>+</p>
        <input type="text" id="second" size="10" onkeyup="sum()"><br>
```

Comment: это оказалось проще, чем я думал. Спасибо